# How to extract field from command result in different versions of linux?

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, tokenize

I was trying to extract a process size using the command:

```
size=`ps -eo vsz,pid | grep $pid | cut -'d' -f1`
```

However, this appeared to only work on some computers but not all. So on the ones where it wasn't working, I tried:

```
size=`ps -eo vsz,pid | grep $pid | awk '{print $1}'`
```

however, now this didn't work on the computers where the first command worked.

What I mean by "working" and "not working" is that sometimes:

```
echo "|$size|"
```

Will return something like:

```
|8762348

9835|
```

And thus the following returns an arithmetic error:

```
(( $size > $threshold ))
```

because of the newline or carriage return characters stored in $size. Is there a way to reliable extract simply the first field across different versions of linux?

Comment: Try: `ps -eo vsz,pid | awk -v pid=$pid '$2 == pid{print $1}'`

Comment: What @anubhava said ... your **problem** is that the value of `$pid` may feature in other strings - it may be part of several pids, or of the size.  The **problem** is not the systems, but your thinking.

Answer (score 0):

First you ask `ps` to displat info for all processes, next you try to select 1 of them.

Your command had problems on `some computers`, and you tagged the question with both `ksh` and `linux`, so I am not sure what command can be used best in your case:

```
size=$(ps -q ${pid} -o vsz --no-headers)
# or
size=$(ps -p ${pid} -o vsz | grep -v "VSZ")
```